# How does aiohttp signal to event loop for IO operation?

Tags: python-3.x, aiohttp

I somewhat understand how asyncio works in Python, I'm also would like to know how does the `aiohttp` package signal to the event loop that it's doing some IO operation, and the event loop should skip to the next task?

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio

async def fetch(session, url):
        async with session.get(url) as response:
            return await response.text()

async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        html = await fetch(session, 'http://python.org')
        print(html)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: I don't understand the question.
aiohttp uses asyncio transport/protocol API, that's it.